# SSH on Raspberry Pi (OpenELEC) not working

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am not able to use SSH to connect to the Raspberry.

Raspberry Pi B+

OpenELEC 5.0.8 (SSH enabled)

wired eth0 (recognized during setup)

10.190.135.xxx IP address

If I ping the said 10.190.135.xxx IP I get "request time out" and SSH to the this IP (Putty) gives "Network error: Connection timed out".

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There's a dedicated Raspberry Pi site (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), which has a higher concentration of RP experts.  If you don't get a good answer here, you might want to post the question there (and delete it from here so you're not cross-posting).

Comment: The Pi is actually connected to the network and able to access it, right? /edit: This is more of a general Linux question. If it was a different product/PC/device, the question would still be the same.

Comment: Are you sure the ssh is enabled and configured correctly? Have you enabled IPTABLES and so prevented access to port 22 or indeed any port? Is the device you are pinging from actually on the same network (e.g. 10.190.135.yyy/255.255.255.0)? Is the device you are pinging from on the same physical network (e.g. on the same switch)?

Answer (score 1):

There's different check to do:

If you have a monitor that you can connect on the raspberry open a command line on the raspberry and

- Check its IP with `ifconfig` or `ip addr`. Is it really `10.190.135.xxx` that you want to connect to.
- Check that you can ping your gateway  and the pc you want to connect from.
- If you installed iptables check with `sudo iptables -L` that you don't have a rule which drops ssh (port 22 usually)
- Check in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that you allow your user to connect to your Pi.

From your computer:

- Check that `ping 10.190.135.xxx` is successful
- If you can do a `ssh -v` to get more informations on what's going wrong and post the result here maybe we can help more.

Comment: At the current stage, checking the SSH configuration is pointless. The message is quite clear: The connection attempt doesn’t even reach `sshd`, or more precisely: The client doesn’t receive an answer.